# CSOM Check Anonymous Access

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, anonymous-access

I'm trying to write some C# CSOM code that creates a report of what websites can be accessed anonymously.

In PowerShell, I would get this info with something like `$webUrl | Get-SPWeb | % { $_.AllowAnonymousAccess -eq $true }`.  Is there an analogous command for C# `Web` objects?

This is referring to this setting on a Site or List:

[image: shows advanced sharing screen in sharepoint]

And the Anonymous Access option shows this:

[image: shows anonymous access dialog in sharepoint]

How do you get this setting from rest api?

Comment: sorry i missed that CSOM part...deleting my answer as it does not apply for CSOM..

Comment: ???  missed what part? I have this same question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

Make a SOAP web service call (there is no rest web service call that can get this):

`POST` to `${sharepointSiteUrl}/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx`

Headers:

- `SOAPAction`=`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetContent`
- `Accept`=`text/xml`

Body:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soap:GetContent>
            <soap:objectType>Site</soap:objectType>
            
            <soap:retrieveChildItems>false</soap:retrieveChildItems>
            <soap:securityOnly>false</soap:securityOnly>
        </soap:GetContent>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response will contain:

`AllowAnonymousAccess="True" AnonymousViewListItems="True"`

These two booleans reflect the status of the checkboxes in the Anonymous Access settings.